# Partial least squares regression for categorical factor in R

Tags: r, categorical-data, multivariate-analysis, partial-least-squares

I adjust the partial least squares regression for one categorical factor (2 levels – `be` or `nottobe`) with with the `pls` package in R. I try to use `round()` function in the predict values for take the decision if the result are the first or second level in my factor. Does this approach sound correct?

```
require(pls) 

#Artificial data  

T<-as.factor(sort(rep(c("be", "nottobe"), 100))) 

y1 <- c(rnorm(100,1,0.1),rnorm(100,1,0.1)) 
y2 <- c(rnorm(100,10,0.3),rnorm(100,10,0.6)) 
y3 <- c(rnorm(100,10,2.3),rnorm(100,11,2.6)) 
y4 <- c(rnorm(100,5,0.5),rnorm(100,7,0.5)) 
y5 <- c(rnorm(100,0,0.1),rnorm(100,0,0.1)) 

#Create the data frame 
avaliacao <- as.numeric(T) 
espectro <- cbind(y1,y2,y3,y4,y5) 
dados <- data.frame(avaliacao = I(as.matrix(avaliacao)), bands = I(as.matrix(espectro))) 

#PLS regression
taumato <- plsr(avaliacao ~ bands, ncomp = 5, validation = "LOO", data=dados) 
summary(taumato) 

#Components analysis 
plot(taumato, plottype = "scores", comps = 1:5) 


#Cross validation 
taumato.cv <- crossval(taumato, segments = 10) 
plot(MSEP(taumato.cv), legendpos = "topright") 
summary(taumato.cv, what = "validation") 
plot(taumato, xlab ="medição", ylab="predição", ncomp = 3, asp = 1, main=" ", line = TRUE) 


#Predition for 3 components 
T<-as.factor(sort(rep(c("be", "nottobe"), 50))) 

y1 <- c(rnorm(100,1,0.1),rnorm(100,1,0.1)) 
y2 <- c(rnorm(100,10,0.3),rnorm(100,10,0.6)) 
y3 <- c(rnorm(100,10,2.3),rnorm(100,11,2.6)) 
y4 <- c(rnorm(100,5,0.5),rnorm(100,7,0.5)) 
y5 <- c(rnorm(100,0,0.1),rnorm(100,0,0.1)) 

espectro2 <- cbind(y1,y2,y3,y4,y5) 
new.dados <- data.frame(bands = I(as.matrix(espectro2))) 
round(predict(taumato, ncomp = 3, newdata = new.dados))##
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- PLS with a "hardening"-threshold to convert the output into hard class decisions is known as PLS-DA, and yes that is frequently done.
- If you go for PLS-DA, you typically want to adjust the threshold for unequal numbers of training cases in the classes.
- However, there are more advanced and possibly also more appropriate possibilities: you can use the PLS as regularization for "proper" classification models such as LDA (PLS-LDA) or logistic regression (PLS-LR; this is a type II nonlinear PLS model according to Rosipal's description).
- Literature:

  - [Barker, M. & Rayens, W.: Partial least squares for discrimination, J Chemom, 17, 166-173 (2003).

    DOI: 10.1002/cem.785](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/cem.785)
  - [Rosipal, R: Nonlinear Partial Least Squares: An Overview, in Chemoinformatics and Advanced Machine Learning Perspectives, Hershey, 2011.](http://aiolos.um.savba.sk/~roman/Papers/npls_book11.pdf)